# Why can i not select the authorisation server when testing an API management function on the Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Having setup API management on Azure and configuring an oAuth2 server to use when trying API's on the development portal I can select the authorisations server in a drop down box at the bottom of the page:

[image: Developer Portal "Try It" page]

However, when I use the Azure portal implementation I cannot select my oAuth server, I only get an option to select the key I want to use even though I can see my oAuth server is setup with the operation in the settings page.

[image: Azure Portal "Test" page]

Is this feature missing on the portal or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "When I use the Azure portal implementation"? Is it not from the Developer Portal?

Comment: To clarify, I mean when I click "Test" next to an operation when I'm editing it on the modern Azure portal (not the developer portal).

Comment: This is definately an issue now the old admin portal has been removed for API management.